# Prevent toggle button from toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I took a simple toggle input from this link : [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch)

I'm trying to prevent the toggle button from toggling.

How can I do that by javascript / jquery / css?

Answer (score 0):

Add css:

```
.switch { pointer-events:none; }
```

If you want a specific one (rather than all) then use an id or an additional class, eg:

```
.switch.notoggle { pointer-events:none; }
```

then

```
<div class='switch notoggle'>
....
```